# Dynamic date case statement

Tags: sql, ssms-2012

I'm using SQL Management Studio 2012.I Have a query output like below.  I would like to have a column that looks at the date completed and if it's greater that 2019-01-01 then the exam is'valid' if earlier then 'Renew'.  It can't be a hardcoded 2019-01-01, at the turn of the year I would like it to be looking at 2020-01-01 and so on.

```
Name         Exam         Date Completed  
Matt         English        2018-11-26       
James        Maths          2019-06-02
```

I would like

```
Name         Exam         Date Completed        Valid
Matt         English        2018-11-26            No
James        Maths          2019-06-02            Yes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you simply want to know if the year is the same as the current year.  That would be:

```
(case when year(date_completed) = year(getdate()) then 'Yes' else 'No'
 end) as valid
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff, I was totally over thinking it!

Answer (score 2):

This also works, but I don't know if it's more or less efficient than the case statement above:

```
    SELECT IIF(YEAR(date_completed) < YEAR(GETDATE()),'No','Yes') AS valid
```

Comment: Thanks @daShier this works too, I haven't used the IIF function before, didn't even know it exisited